# PHP: Best Method for Sequential Output?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

What is the best approach for setting up sequential output for a PHP installer script? Say I have a page, and want to display incremental output within a DIV provided by a PHP script.

So `page.html` might contain this:

```
<div id="output">
    <!-- Script Output Here -->
</div>
```

And install.php might look like this (for testing purposes):

```
<?php
// Turn off Output Buffering
ob_end_flush();

// Begin Test Output (5 second intervals)
echo 'Testing incremental output...' . "\n";
sleep(5);
echo 'Step 1...' . "\n";
sleep(5);
echo 'Step 2...' . "\n";
sleep(5);
echo 'Complete!' . "\n";
```

I was thinking AJAX might be the best approach, but I'm not sure how to approach that. If I load "install.php" via JavaScript, I won't get everything back until the script finishes execution (correct?) - making this entire goal moot. I've seen this done before, but can't find a concrete example of how it was done.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt Ajax will do what you want - instead you may have to call the ajax fetches more frequently.

For flushing information out as soon as it's produced you need regular `flush()`'s after outputting information.

I've also added into a relevant .htaccess file a line to avoid any buffering due to GZipping the output as well (apache2).

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/url/dont/buffer/me.php" gzip=0
```

In the relevant PHP file:

```
ini_set('output_buffering', false);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 'true');
```

and the appropriate calls to flush(). That pretty much covers all the bases.

Answer (score -2):

I would output everything to a text file and updating the DIV via AJAX by just calling the .txt file

Comment: Pretty hairy; multiple users? Then you've got multiple text files. Name the text file based on a session? What about multiple tabs? Oh crap I just divided by zero.

Comment: Ah, screw it. Just time your install script and create an animated GIF. It's all the same to the user.